# Table View / Scroll View: Scroll not smooth when adjusting Content Inset property in function scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, scrollview

I have successfully made a table view 'stretchy header' by adjusting the content offset and content inset top property in `viewDidLoad`.

However, i also have a section header in my table view and because of adjusting the content inset top property, the section header gets left behind when scrolled up

[image]

As a solution, inside the `scrollViewDidScroll`, once the content offset reaches a certain threshold, i update the content inset top property to the current offset.

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  if scrollView.contentOffset.y > -tableViewOffset {

      scrollView.contentInset.top = max(0, -scrollView.contentOffset.y)

  }

}
```

This solves my section header problem. However, the scroll is not smooth / bouncy. It's not accelerating and de accelerating. Is there an alternate solution where i can continually adjust the content offset property for a smoother scroll experience?

Comment: Hi, did you ever found any solution to your problem, currently facing exact same problem.

Comment: Nope I didn't, I didn't spend too much time on this. Do let me know if you find a fix for this.